# Ubuntu 15.10 No Wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

I am brand new to Ubuntu and the forums, and I know very little. So please keep all help simple. I can handle code, but no skipped steps please. Also, if one step needs prior knowledge, I won't know it. I got ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 3520 model. I have 15.10. My wifi is out, and I don't know why. I have had Vista, Ubunt 14.10, 15.06, and 15.10, and all have thwarted me of wifi by no drivers. In the extra driver section, it says:

> Broadcom Corporation: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (Wireless 1704 802.22n + BT 4.0)
>   This device is not working.
>   Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)

I have tried to download it here, and failed. I have tried many methods, and none have worked. I tried all marked "Answered". I don't know what else to put in. If you need anything, tell me what. Ethernet works.

Comment: From the sound of it, Linux just doesn't support your wireless card yet. Before you install every driver and kernel module you can find on the World Wide Web, you should figure out if there even is a driver that can support your chipset in the mainline kernel and, if so, what is causing the problem. A kernel update could help...

Comment: First of all, @andrew-steele, can you use cable for some time to install driver?

Comment: I have taken the card out before, so it may be busted. I doubt it though. Also, I do not believe that there is an existing driver for it yet. There was a fix for 14.10 though. I just found that out.

Comment: I found a possible fix. On the software center, there is an app for windows wireless drivers. I requires the newest version of ubuntu possible. Will it work?

Comment: I fixed it guys. I found the answer through extensive research and luck. If you want to know how I did it, I'll tell you.

Comment: @AndrewSteele please tell me. My 43142 is freaking me out since the first moment.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, make a dvd with the .iso with the latest version of ubuntu on it. Open the dvd. Click on the following: pool>restricted>b>bcmwl and drop the file on the desktop. Next go to pool>main>d>dkms and drop the file on the desktop. Both files should be .deb  Next open the terminal(Control Alt T). Type in the command:
cd ~/Desktop
and then:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
if there is an error, type the command:
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
and then:
ps cax | grep PID
if it is running then type:
kill PID

## wait

kill -9 PID
type this next:
ps cax | grep PID
then type:
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
and finally:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
after typing that repeat:
sudo dpkg --configure -a
and finally type:
sudo modprobe wl
this will unlock your wifi. If it is still blocked by hardware switch, then type:
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
your wifi will be fixed. If not, look elsewhere for answers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after upgrading my Ubuntu 15.04 version to 15.10, It didn't recognize my wireless card. What I did was:

1) Run:  lspci |grep Wireless  (you will get your wireless driver chipset)

2) Download the firmware for my hardware from Intel support site and install it (# sudo cp iwlwifi-7260-15.ucode /lib/firmware/)

3) Download the drivers for my configuration from Broadcom support site, because when running: "sudo modprobe wl" y got the error message: "wl module not found". http://www.broadcom.com/support/?gid=1 (I picked: Linux® STA 64-bit driver --> hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271)

4) # make  (to build the wl module)
   # sudo make install  (install)

5) Reboot

Done!. So now I have my WiFi working properly again :)

**Additional Steps** 
Because a I have an Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260, it has some problems when enabling both bluetooth and WiFi, so I also had to do:

6)  sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
    add the line -->  blacklist btusb

7)  sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
    comment everything