# BCM43142 stops working randomly after upgrading to 15.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, 15.10

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 5520, the wireless network is BCM43142 which doesn't work properly after upgrading to 15.10.

It works for a while and stop working without any error or notification, after a minutes or two or after disabling/enabling the network it start working again. This cycle never stops!

I'm suspicious that the problem was there before upgrading but I'm sure it got worse.

I've purged and reinstalled `bcmwl-kernel-source` but nothing changed.

How can I figure out the real problem?

Comment: My computer has the same chip, but it stopped working altogether. I fixed it, so the answer may be at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/689174/ubuntu-15-10-no-wifi/689499#689499
This was a fix with the same chip, but a different computer. The chip stopped working, so it may not be the answer you are looking for. Again, this was for a chip that wasn't working at all, and yours seems to be working some. So, it may or may not be the answer.